# MGL inductor for impedance matching

Tags: impedance-matching

Has anyone ever used TDK MLG inductor for impedance matching?

It is very small, how am I gonna connect it to my circuit?

http://product.tdk.com/en/catalog/datasheets/inductor_commercial_high-frequency_mlg1005s_en.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an 0402 get some tweezers, man up and solder it down. Grab a magnifying glass or a microscope if you have trouble seeing it.  Just dab some solder on one pad, heat it up, slide it in with the tweezers and solder the other side :)

Comment: Does that mean I have to find a circuit board with 2 pads exactly this small distance? And then lay down the inductor and solder 2 ends of this inductor onto the board?

Comment: Yes and no.  You were talking impedance matching so I assumed you would have a board you were working on.  You can also solder one end to a pin, and then solder some magnet or 30 gauge wire to the other end of it to make the other connection.  It might take a few tries but it's something we do all the time.  They also make 0402 breakout boards (sparkfun), and surfboards (digikey) that might work for you.  On the other hand just wiring something in like that may not be in line with your desire to impedance match something.

Comment: I'm doing impedance matching for an NMR sample holder, which means there is no board. I have a pin going out of sample holder where I can solder a variable capacitor. So how would you recommend for how I should place this tiny inductor?

Answer (score 0):

That is a surface mount device (SMD). You connect it by soldering to your printed circuit board. You can see the recommended trace pattern on page 5 of the manual.